# Joining on Row_Number() in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm trying to join a CTE on itself by using `row_number()`.

Using this syntax

```
select row_number() over(order by x.patientid, x.dischargedate) as rn
         ,* from x
    inner join x as x2 on row_number() over(order by x.patientid,    x.dischargedate)=row_number() over(order by x2.patientid, x2.dischargedate)
```

The CTE `x` does what I want it to but when I try to join on the row number I get the error
`Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.`

I know that I can include the row_number in the CTE itself and give it a column name and then join on something like `x.rn` but is there any logical reason I can't think of as to why you can't directly join on the function `row_number()`?

Comment: It is because it gets calculated only before order by is performed, after all the rows query will return are known.

Comment: The query u put is not the CTE, CTE is always start from WITH keyword,
the code is not CTE one.
it is possible to make a join on CTE.
the concept you are talking is the Recursive CTE.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not a full CTE; my point was that if I had a CTE (named X) I could have entered in the `row_number() clause there and not encountered this problem.  I was merely wondering what I typed wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In the join condition of an inner join you are performing a filter on the cartesian product of the two tables. Your operation row_number() over (order by x.a, x.b) would therefore not be an operation on table x but on the cartesian production.

If you would have it in the join condition, the system would just in the phase of determining the candidate rows of your select. You cannot have an operation that has its semantics defined only on the *result* rows in use for *finding* those result rows. The filter would change the result and the result would change the filter.

The difference with the CTE is that you define your row_number column on an intermediate result set and *then* do the join.